# Display div every second loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a `div` to every second item in my wordpress loop. Currently I am using the code below (which works) but I presume there is a much nicer/cleaner way to do it. How would I change the code below? Any recommendations as to where to look would be great, too, as this seems messy to me. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php            
  $col_select = $data['example_select'];
  if ($col_select == '2 Col') {
    get_template_part( '/templates/article/content', 'standard' ); ?>
<?php if( $wp_query->current_post == '1') { ?>
  </div><div class="row">
<?php } if( $wp_query->current_post == '3') { ?>
  </div><div class="row">
<?php } if( $wp_query->current_post == '5') { ?>
  </div><div class="row">
<?php } if( $wp_query->current_post == '7') { ?>
  </div><div class="row">
<?php } if( $wp_query->current_post == '9') { ?>
  </div><div class="row">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if( $wp_query->current_post % 2 != 0)` should do it.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Edit: Of course, if you ever delete a post it will break, but this is based off your current code. Where is the loop that this bit is in? You could use a counter to do it.

Comment: Haha I was just writing that as you wrote it!

Comment: Brillant. So simple.... I will accept when it lets me jessica

Answer (score 1):

Even

```
if($wp_query->current_post % 2)
```

would do that for %2, because 1 = true and 0 = false

Comment: Though, this breaks if we decide to throw three things into the column, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php            
        $col_select = $data['example_select'];
    if ($col_select == '2 Col')
    {
        get_template_part( '/templates/article/content', 'standard' ); ?>
        <?php if(($wp_query->current_post % 2) == 1) { ?>
            </div><div class="row">
        <?php } ?>
```

`current_post % 2` will return 1 if it's an odd number.

Comment: @ollieread No, it will return 0 for an even number. He is correct that it will be 1 for an odd number.

Comment: No, it won't. The remainder of an odd number divided by 2 is 1.  It will return 0 if it is even, just like Jessica's alternative answer below.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid opening and closing the `<?php ... ?>` tags as much as possible. This inhibits being able to read your code. Secondly, if you want to end your `div` every other row, then use a modulo test, like so:

```
<?php 
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $col_select = $data['example_select'];
    if ($col_select == '2 Col') {
      get_template_part( '/templates/article/content', 'standard' ); 
      if ( $wp_query->current_post % 2 == 1 ) {
        echo "</div><div class=\"row\">";
      }
    }
  endwhile;
?>
```

However, the truly clean way to do this is to defer display to the template you're rendering here. Without knowing what you're using for `get_template_part`, it's a little hard to say how you'd pass in the appropriate data (which is the 'next two' parts of your query.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus approach is the correct one, but the options given do break if `$wp_query->current_post` isn't returning incremental numbers.

Best thing to do, would be create another variable to store the amount of times you've looped, like the following.

```
<?php 
$x = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $col_select = $data['example_select'];
    if ($col_select == '2 Col')
    {
        get_template_part( '/templates/article/content', 'standard' );
        if(($x % 2) == 1) { ?>
            </div><div class="row">
        <?php }
        $x++;
    }
endwhile;
```

The above means that for every second result for the `2 Col` match you'll have `</div><div class="row">` output.